# Is Cesaro convergence still weaker in measure?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I've encountered a question I couldn't answer, and I would appreciate any help:
Is it true that $$f_n \xrightarrow{m}0\,\,\implies \,\,\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k \xrightarrow{m}0$$ where $(X,{\mathcal{B}},m)$ is a probability space, and $\xrightarrow{m}$ means: $\forall \epsilon>0,\,  m\left(|f_n|\geq \epsilon\right) \rightarrow 0.$

This is similar to Cesaro convergence, which is weaker than regular convergence, but it is not the case here. I've tried to prove the proposition, or to give a counter example, but didn't manage to succeed in either. Any insights will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

No, $f_n \stackrel m \to 0$ does not imply $\frac 1 n \sum_{k = 1} ^ n f_k \stackrel m \to 0$. In fact, if $P(X_n = n) = \frac 1 n$ and $X_n = 0$ otherwise, with $X_1, X_2, ...$ independent, it is a nice little exercise to show that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{n}$ converges in distribution to a nondegenerate random variable.

Just to explicitly give a counterexample, consider $P(X_n = x_n) = \frac 1 n$ and $X_n = 0$ otherwise with $x_n$ increasing. Then $X_n \to 0$ in probability. But for even $n$, $$\sum_{k = 1} ^ n X_k \ge x_{n / 2} I(X_k \ne 0 \mbox{ for some $k \ge \frac n 2$})$$ since $x_n$ is increasing. So $$\sum_{k = 1} ^ k X_k \ge x_{n / 2}$$ with at least probability $$P(X_k \ne 0 \mbox{ for some $k \ge \frac n 2$}) = 1 - \prod_{k = n/2} ^ n \frac{k - 1}{k} = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 n.$$ So, $\frac{\sum_{k = 1} ^ n X_k}{n} \ge \frac {x_{n / 2}} n$ with at least probability $\frac 1 2$. If $\frac{x_{n / 2}} n$ doesn't go to $0$ then this shows $\frac{\sum_{k = 1} ^ n X_k} n$ won't go to $0$ in probability; for example, if $x_n = n$ this shows that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{n} \ge \frac 1 2$ with probability at least $\frac 1 2$ for even $n$.

Comment: I couldn't really follow after your deductions in the answer, but tried to investigate myself the case of $f_n=n \chi_{[0,^{1}_{n}]}$. I actually got to other conclusion than yours- Cesaro limit in measure does exist and equals zero, in this case. You've used an unexplained assumption about the sets being "independent" thus letting yourself using multiplication of measures. I'm not sure it's correct in the general case. Anyway, if I'm wrong, and your answer is correct, I would appreciate it if you could write in terms of measure theory, so it would fit the question.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that the $X_i$ are independent. It isn't true in general; in the case of $f_n = n \chi_{[0, \frac 1 n]}$ you should get that the Cesaro-means converge to $0$ because the $f_n$ converge to $0$ *almost surely*. If you have almost sure convergence to $0$, Cesaro convergence to $0$ almost surely is trivial, which implies convergence in measure to $0$ for probability measures.

Comment: To formalize the argument I gave in measure theory, you could probability take $X = \{0, 1\}^\infty$ where $x \in X$ is a binary sequence $(x_1, x_2, ...)$, $\mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra, $f_n(x) = n \chi_{x_n = 1}$, and $m$ the product measure of $m_n(\{1\}) = \frac 1 n$ and $m_n(\{0\}) = 1 - m_n(\{1\})$.

Comment: Okay thanks. This does explain the given example is not good.

Comment: @Snir not sure what you mean, I do still claim the argument in my answer shows the answer to your original question is "no."

Comment: Nice answer +1. In the case that $x_n=n$, any idea if you can also show that $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k>n$ with some positive probability? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JimmyR. in the case of $x_n = n$, you can show that $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k / n $ converges in distribution to a nondegenerate random variable. It is also easy to check that it has mean $1$. So we must have $\Pr(Z_n > 1)$ bounded away from 0, equivalently $\sum_k X_k > n$ has probability bounded away from 0.

Comment: @guy Thanks for your response. I have so many questions, that I think I will become a burden: First, I do not know how to show convergence to a nondegenerate, second how to show mean 1, third I think this assumes that the means also converge (which does not follow from distribution) so it confuses me more. The last implication is only ok (if Pr(Zn>1) then clearly ΣX_k>n is bounded away from 0, this is clear to me. I think, I shall post a question so that you can answer these questions properly and take your credit! Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: I will try them by myself first, but If I post a question I will let you know. Thanks again!